# Why does a regex match the end of a group to the second match?

Tags: regex

I am confused about why the following regex:

```
CHANGES:(.|\n)*(\*\/)
```

matches to the second comment closing (`*/`)instead of the first in the following block:

```
 /* ysqwwqdeqwd 
 Some general start comments and code description

 DESCRIPTION:

    Interface for c

 CHANGES:

    $Log: blala.h,v $
    Revision 1.7  2008/09/08 18:34:43  p
    Updated copyright year.
 */

#define startofcode yeah

/* General include files for Object Oriented C code.
 */
#include "oo.h"
#include "const.h"
#include "libmath.h"
```

here we would get this:

```
CHANGES:
    ...

 */

#define startofcode yeah

/* General include files for Object Oriented C code.
 */
```

instead of just:

```
CHANGES:
        ...

     */
```

[here is a live example.](https://regex101.com/r/rJ7hJ6/2) The background here is that i am trying to remove a bunch of old CVS style svn commit logs from the top of a bunch of `.h` files that are no longer needed.

Comment: that's because `.*` is greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CHANGES:(.|\n)*?(\*\/)

              ^^
```

You need `non greedy` regex.See demo.When you use `greedy` regex it will stop at the last instance of `*/`.When you use non greedy it will stop at the first instance of `*/`.`*` is greedy and will consume as much as it can.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0sZ0/3

Comment: Do you have a short explanation of why?

Comment: Actually, as a further question, there are more `*/` in that file, why does it stop on the second one?

Comment: @Ben can you show the sample?coz it will stop only at the last instance .

Comment: Sorry, you are totally right ... I had more in the code, but not more in my regex tester.. Sorry.